# How to add a custom field on register page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have to add a custom drop down field about " where did you hear about us ? " on customer register page. How can i add it in magento ??

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please make an effort to do this yourself / research how it can be done before asking on SO.. [Google's first result](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields) pretty much sums up your lack of research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this **[tutorial](http://lap-trinh.com/article/50714b0621126)**.

Please let me know if you have any problem with this tutorial. Hope this help

Comment: thank you for the tutorial i'll try this and let you know. I tried following tutorial but it didn't work http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6

Comment: Why didn't work. It's also a good tutorial. Let me know your problem.

Comment: in this tutorial http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6 my installer script is not running. I tried it comparing version and all other stuffs but still its not working. I am creating a custom module for it but still it doesn't work

Comment: So, you need to check your setup script on core_resource table. Find you setup script and delete this script from core_resource table. Then, reload again. Let me know any problem.

Comment: i already did that, in the first place there is no entry in core_resource. I also double checked the version. I added values into database using sql raw query. but still facing error.